# Efficiently plotting multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to efficiently plot groups of multiple columns in a pandas dataframe.

I have the following dataframe

```
        | a | b | c |...|trial1.1|trial1.2|...|trial1.12|trial2.1|...|trial2.12|trial3.1|...|trial3.12|
GlobalID|
sd12f   |...|...|...|...| 210.1  | 213.1  |...| 170.1   | 176.2  |...| 160.31  | 162.4  |...| 186.1   | 
...
```

I would like to loop through the rows and for each row plot three waveforms: `trial1.[1-12]`, `trial2.[1-12]`, `trial3.[1-12]`. What is the most efficient way to do this? Right now I have:

```
t1 = df.ix[0][df.columns[[colname.startswith('trial1') for colname in df]]]
t2 = df.ix[0][df.columns[[colname.startswith('trial2') for colname in df]]]
t3 = df.ix[0][df.columns[[colname.startswith('trial3') for colname in df]]]
t1.astype(float).plot()
t2.astype(float).plot()
t3.astype(float).plot()
```

I need the `.astype(float)` because the values are originally strings. Is there some  more efficient way of doing this I am missing? I am new to python and pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about first transverse the dataframe, then split the dataframe by trials, then plot.

```
# Transverse
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt").T

# Insert your code to remove irrelevant rows, like a, b, c in your example
#

# Group by the trial number (the first six characters) and plot
data.groupby(lambda x: x[:6], axis=0).plot()
```

Comment: right now I remove the irrelevant rows by `t1 = df.ix[0][df.columns[[colname.startswith('trial1') for colname in df]]]` Is that the best way?

Comment: That definitely works, or you could do df.index.map(lambda x: x.startswith('trial')). Here df is the transverse dataframe.