# plotting multiple columns simultaneously in pythons

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I have a text file with some columns. I am trying to make `scatter plot` from some of the columns in my file. I made a list of the items (column names) that I want to make a plot for. I would like to make the scatter plot for all items in the list against other items.

expected output:
if there are 3 columns to be plotted, I would like to get these plots simultaneously:

```
1 vs 2
1 vs 3
2 vs 1
2 vs 3
3 vs 1
3 vs 2
```

to do so I made the following code in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep="\t")
columns = list(df.columns.values)[3:] #to make a list of items
for i in len(columns):
    ax = sns.lmplot(x=columns[i], y=columns[i+1], data=df)
    ax.savefig(f'{columns[i]}.pdf')
```

but it does not return the expected outputs. do you know how to fix the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently plotting multiple columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559160/efficiently-plotting-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: no actually this is not duplicate of this post.